# Quick way to read the next string from a file without moving the position of the file

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

I'm wondering what is the best way to read what the next string is in a file (to check if it matches a string) without increasing the position of the cursor in the file. So basically I want to read the next string without reading the next string.

Comment: How about reading it and then rewinding the cursor

Comment: @UKMonkey that was my solution, but I was wondering if there was a quicker way to solve this problem. If not, this is the solution I will stick with.

Comment: You can use `peek()` to get next character, but I won't allow to get more than one char.

Comment: What makes you think that rewinding the cursor is not fast? C++ libraries are highly optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the next string without changing the cursor as long as you use the same ifstream object, but you can save and restore the position:

```
auto p = stream.tellg();
// do what ever read you like
stream.seekg(p, std::ios_base::beg);
```

If your read failes you may have to clear the error flags before calling seekg().

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I used, but I was curious if there was an alternative way of solving this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: You can use peek() to get the next item from the stream without changing the cursor. If this returns the "wrong" character you do not need to tell / read / seek. Perhaps this will lead to a better performance.